# Get an inventory of installed software

Tags: powershell

im having issues to create an inventory of software from my domain, i have this starting code  i thought it will work but this code take the base specifications of the command `Get-Adcomputer` and if i execute the $result line alone with a out-gridView it list me my local software i dont know why i cant get listed the software of other device. Hope i explain myself and sorry for my bad english

```
$displayName = 'Adobe Acrobat DC (64-bit)'
$key = 'Registry::HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$Appkey = Get-ChildItem -Path:$key | Where-Object {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $displayName}
$Appkey.PSChildName

$Appkey | Select-Object name | Split-Path -Parent


#$Result = @() # create an array
#We create a variable who can take all AdComputers

$computers =Get-ADComputer -Filter *

#Here we find the name of the computer, the group of a single program and when we install it
$Result = foreach ($computer in $computers){
    $nombre =  $computer.Name

    if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $nombre -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet)) {
        Write-Host "Conexion fallida con $nombre offline" -ForegroundColor Red
        continue  
    }
       
    try{
        
        $Name        = Get-CimInstance  Win32_product -ComputerName $nombre | Select-Object Name
        $PackageName = Get-CimInstance  Win32_product -ComputerName $nombre | Select-Object PackageName
        $InstallDate = Get-CimInstance  Win32_product -ComputerName $nombre | Select-Object InstallDate

        [PsCustomObject] @{
            ComputerName  = $Name.Name
            PackageName   = $PackageName.PackageName
            InstallDate   = $InstallDate.InstallDate
        }
        }
catch {
        Write-Warning "Error en la comunicacion con: $serverName, escaneando siguiente"   
    }
  }
#here we export to the destination file

$Result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\softin.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Remember that not all software is registered in `Win32_Product`; those will not be registered in the inventory.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Foreach loop:

```
$displayName = 'Adobe Acrobat DC (64-bit)'
$key = 'Registry::HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$Appkey = Get-ChildItem -Path:$key | Where-Object {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $displayName}
$Appkey.PSChildName

$Appkey | Select-Object name | Split-Path -Parent


$Result = @() # create an array
#We create a variable who can take all AdComputers

$computers =Get-ADComputer -Filter *

#Here we find the name of the computer, the group of a single program and when we install it
$Result = foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    $Ping = Test-Connection $computer.samaccountname -Count 1 -Quiet
    if ($Ping)
    {
        Write-Host "Computer Found: $($computer.samaccountname)" -ForegroundColor Green
        get-ciminstance win32_product -ComputerName $computer.Samaccountname | Select-object Name, PackageName, InstallDate
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Computer NOT Found: $($computer.samaccountname)" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}

#here we export to the destination file

$Result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\softin.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: [1] Please do not use `+=` to add new items to an array as you do in `$Result +=`. This is a wasteful thing to do as the **entire** array needs to be recreated in memory. Instead use `$Result = foreach ($computer in $computers) {..}` and inside the loop simply output whatever you select from `Get-CimInstance`. [2] a Registry path is either `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, not a mixture of both.  Then there is also the `Wow6432Node` path to consider

Comment: When i run the scriptof @Judd Davey y execute but do nothing so i try to add a code who check me the computers that  i cannot reach and the script get infinite doing nothing this lines that i added are in the foreach loop but nothing happens with and without those lines

Comment: Is there anything inside of the ```$Computers``` variable?

Comment: Yes, in that variable take all my turned on devices  of my domain with the `Get-Adcomputer -filter *`  and with your foreach it should take the name of the device, packagename and the install date of the programs from each pc  but it does  nothing.

Comment: Instead of ```get-ciminstance win32_product ``` can you try ```Get-WmiObject win32_product```

Comment: I try with both but we have the same result the txt file is empty.

Comment: Does ```$Result``` contain anything?

Comment: It contains the specified data of ` get-ciminstance win32_product -ComputerName $computer | Select-object Name, PackageName, InstallDate` to print in to the txt file every loop of the for each in theory if i run the script it give me an error that says "The RCP server is not accesible"

Comment: I have updated my original answer to include a $Ping variable that checks if the computer is online

Answer (score 0):

Windows powershell (5.1) only:

```
get-package
```

Comment: I use the command and change a few things of the code and now in the export CSV and  get a Systemobject [] i edit my first code with the moded code.